# ImmGetContext returns zero always

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to make Korean key logger.

To do that, I need to check IME mode of the current(foreground) window.
I tried to implement this using the `ImmGetContext` function, but `ImmGetContext(GetForegroundWindow())` returns zero always.

How can I fix this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <immdev.h>
#include <imm.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "imm32")
using namespace std;

void WINAPI GetProcessNameByProcessID(DWORD dwProcessID, LPWSTR lpszProcessName, size_t nMaxCount) {
    HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
    if (hSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        PROCESSENTRY32 processEntry;
        processEntry.dwSize = sizeof(processEntry);
        Process32First(hSnapshot, &processEntry);
        do {
            if (processEntry.th32ProcessID == dwProcessID) {
                wcscpy_s(lpszProcessName, nMaxCount, processEntry.szExeFile);
                break;
            }
        } while (Process32Next(hSnapshot, &processEntry));
        CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
    }
}

int main() {
    //LoadLibrary(L"imm32.dll");

    while (true) {
        WCHAR szName[100];
        DWORD foregroundProcess;
        HWND foregroundWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(foregroundWindow, &foregroundProcess);
        GetProcessNameByProcessID(foregroundProcess, szName, 100);
        
        HIMC hIMC;
        DWORD dwConv, dwSent;
        if (!(hIMC = ImmGetContext(foregroundWindow))) return 1; //Error
        ImmSetOpenStatus(hIMC, true);
        ImmGetConversionStatus(hIMC, &dwConv, &dwSent);

        wcout << szName << L"(" << foregroundProcess << L") : " 
            << (dwConv & IME_CMODE_HANGEUL ? L"KOREAN" : L"ENGLISH") << endl;

        ImmReleaseContext(foregroundWindow, hIMC);

        Sleep(1000);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ImmGetContext is usually called in a result to WM_IME_COMPOSITION https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/processing-the-wm-ime-composition-message not sure it works outside of this, and/or outside of any window(ed) context.

Comment: @SimonMourier // Thank you for your answer. As you said, I tried ImmGetContext inside WndProc and it works well. However, as in the question, I want to create a Korean keylogger, but using WndProc cannot process messages from other processes. Is there any other way? (I tried using WH_KEYBOARD_LL, but it doesn't work.)

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* is not a problem statement.

Comment: @IInspectable // I'm not sure exactly how to explain it. To be as detailed as possible, in the WndProc callback function, the ImmGetContext function returns a non-zero. but in the LowLevelKeyboardHook callback function, the ImmGetContext function returns zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "imm32.lib")
#define IMC_GETOPENSTATUS 0x0005
using namespace std;

int main() {
    while (true) {
        HWND hIME = ImmGetDefaultIMEWnd(GetForegroundWindow());
        LRESULT status = SendMessage(hIME, WM_IME_CONTROL, IMC_GETOPENSTATUS, 0);
        cout << (status ? "Korean" : "English") << endl;
        Sleep(100);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

< References >

ImmGetDefaultIMEWnd Function
https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/windows/win32/api/imm/nf-imm-immgetdefaultimewnd

WM_IME_CONTROL Message
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/wm-ime-control

IMC_GETOPENSTATUS(0x5) & IMC_GETCONVERSIONMODE(0x1)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms920838(v=msdn.10)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms920931(v=msdn.10)

IMC_GETOPENSTATUS and IMC_GETCONVERSIONMODE are not officially supported in Windows 10. However, it seems to be almost the only way to implement what I want, and it works fine. I hope this article is helpful. (Google Translate)

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.