# Unable to link imm32.dll in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dllimport

I'm trying to use a `ImmGetContext()` from `<imm.h>` in a Visual Studio 2022 project, which gives the following errors:

```
1>Project.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ImmGetContext referenced in function "void __cdecl activeWindowChangeHandler(struct HWINEVENTHOOK__ *,unsigned long,struct HWND__ *,long,long,unsigned long,unsigned long)" (?activeWindowChangeHandler@@YAXPEAUHWINEVENTHOOK__@@KPEAUHWND__@@JJKK@Z)
1>Project.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ImmGetConversionStatus referenced in function "void __cdecl activeWindowChangeHandler(struct HWINEVENTHOOK__ *,unsigned long,struct HWND__ *,long,long,unsigned long,unsigned long)" (?activeWindowChangeHandler@@YAXPEAUHWINEVENTHOOK__@@KPEAUHWND__@@JJKK@Z)
1>C:\Users\username\Project\x64\Debug\Project.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

I tried adding `imm32.dll` from the OS itself to the project's Project -> Linker -> General as well as Linker options. It seems to be recognized but couldn't be parsed, here are the new errors after the change:

```
1>C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x2D0
```

Either the one in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\` or `C:\Windows\System32\` could not be parsed correctly.

Here is the code I'm trying to implement:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

void CALLBACK activeWindowChangeHandler(HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook, DWORD dwEvent, HWND hwnd, LONG idObject, LONG idChild, DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime) {
    DWORD dwConversion, dwSentence;
    auto himc = ImmGetContext(hwnd);
    if (ImmGetConversionStatus(himc, &dwConversion, &dwSentence)) {
        wcout << L"Current conversion mode: " << dwConversion << L"sentence mode: " << dwSentence << endl;
    }
    else {
        wcout << L"Failed to get conversion mode" << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    auto hEvent = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, NULL, activeWindowChangeHandler, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS);
    while (true);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Library name is at the bottom of [the page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/imm/nf-imm-immgetcontext).  So "imm32.lib", not the .dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I'm doing it in a totally wrong way. Adding `#pragma comment(lib, "imm32")` to the code have solved the problem.

Thanks to [ImmGetContext returns zero always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64280975/immgetcontext-returns-zero-always)

Answer (score 0):

the library you are using is supposed to be for Win32 you should include imm.h and immdev.h

```
#include <immdev.h>
#include <imm.h>
```