How to get current IME input mode
The korean layout has alphabet mode and hangul mode.


I only need hangul mode in the korean layout. To suppress alphabet mode I wrote this code but I could not find the way to get current IME mode. Which Windows API can I use to implement checkKoreanInputMode() function?
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

bool checkKoreanInputMode() {
    // check current IME layout and mode
}

void setKoreanInputMode() {
    keybd_event(VK_HANGUL, 0, 0, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_HANGUL, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
}

int main() {
    while (true) {
        if (!checkKoreanInputMode()) {
            std::cout << "Switching to Korean input mode." << std::endl;
            setKoreanInputMode();
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
    return 0;
}

I tried to use ImmGetConversionStatus(), but ImmGetContext() returns always NULL even if I changed IME.
bool checkKoreanInputMode() {
    // Get the current IME context
    HIMC hIMC = ImmGetContext(GetForegroundWindow());
    if (hIMC == NULL){
        return false;
    }

    // Get the current IME mode
    DWORD dwConversion = 0, dwSentence = 0;
    bool isKoreanInputMode = false;

    if (ImmGetConversionStatus(hIMC, &dwConversion, &dwSentence)) {
        // Check if the current mode is Korean IME with English input mode
        isKoreanInputMode = (dwConversion & IME_CMODE_NATIVE) && !(dwConversion & IME_CMODE_ALPHANUMERIC);
    }

    // Release the IME context
    ImmReleaseContext(GetForegroundWindow(), hIMC);

    return isKoreanInputMode;
}

What am I doing wrong?

As @AndrásVarró indicated, I remember the imeapps sample which can get notified with WM_IME_NOTIFY and ImmGetConversionStatus.

Thanks for your comment and answer. But I could not use ImmGetConversionStatus() function and WM_IME_NOTIFY. Can you show me how to use it?

Try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64285429/15511041, ImmGetDefaultIMEWnd and WM_IME_CONTROL.

It returns keyboard layout that is korean or english. I need to know mode of korean keyboard layout. The mode can be latin or hangul.

Although these values are not explained, you can test and utilize these values for your requirement.

There are English keyboard layout and Korean keyboard layout. The Korean keyboard layout have two modes, latin and hangul. As far as I understand your code checks keyboard layout. I want to know current IME mode inside Korean keyboard layout.

As @AndrásVarró indicated, I found the imeapps sample which can get notified with WM_IME_NOTIFY and ImmGetConversionStatus.
The following code is adapted from the imeapps sample.
   case WM_IME_NOTIFY:
    {
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case IMN_SETCONVERSIONMODE:
        {
            HIMC hIMC = ImmGetContext(hwnd);
            BOOL fOpen = ImmGetOpenStatus(hIMC);
            DWORD dwConvMode = 0, dwSentMode = 0;
            ImmGetConversionStatus(hIMC, &dwConvMode, &dwSentMode);
            if (fOpen)
            {
                switch (dwConvMode & IME_CMODE_LANGUAGE)
                {
                case IME_CMODE_ALPHANUMERIC:
                    //IME_CMODE_ALPHANUMERIC
                    break;   
                case IME_CMODE_NATIVE:
                    //IME_CMODE_NATIVE
                    break;  
                case (IME_CMODE_NATIVE | IME_CMODE_KATAKANA):
                    //IME_CMODE_KATAKANA
                    break;    
                default:
                    //NULL
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
        }
        break;
    }

Update @ironsand :
I tested these undocumented values with WM_IME_CONTROL. Maybe you can use 0x01.
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "imm32.lib")
#define IMC_GETOPENSTATUS 0x0005
using namespace std;

int main() {
    while (true) {
        HWND hIME = ImmGetDefaultIMEWnd(GetForegroundWindow());
        LRESULT status = SendMessage(hIME, WM_IME_CONTROL, IMC_GETOPENSTATUS, 0);
        cout << (status ? "Korean" : "English") << endl;

        status = SendMessage(hIME, WM_IME_CONTROL, 0x01, 0);
        cout << status << "-0x01" << endl;
        /*status = SendMessage(hIME, WM_IME_CONTROL, 0x02, 0);
        cout << status << "-0x02" << endl;
        status = SendMessage(hIME, WM_IME_CONTROL, 0x03, 0);
        cout << status << "-0x03" << endl;
        status = SendMessage(hIME, WM_IME_CONTROL, 0x04, 0);
        cout << status << "-0x04" << endl;
        status = SendMessage(hIME, WM_IME_CONTROL, 0x06, 0);
        cout << status << "-0x06" << endl;
        status = SendMessage(hIME, WM_IME_CONTROL, 0x0D, 0);
        cout << status << "-0x0D" << endl;
        status = SendMessage(hIME, WM_IME_CONTROL, 0x0E, 0);
        cout << status << "-0x0E" << endl;
        status = SendMessage(hIME, WM_IME_CONTROL, 0x11, 0);
        cout << status << "-0x11" << endl;
        status = SendMessage(hIME, WM_IME_CONTROL, 0x12, 0);
        cout << status << "-0x12" << endl;
        status = SendMessage(hIME, WM_IME_CONTROL, 0x13, 0);
        cout << status << "-0x13" << endl;*/

        Sleep(10000);
    }
    return 0;
}


